# Laravel foreign keys don' work in migration

Tags: laravel, migration

I am trying to link 2 tables in a laravel migration. But I keep getting the General error: 1215. And I don't know why.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('videoNr');
            $table->char('filenaam');
            $table->timestamp('upload_datum')->useCurrent();
            $table->integer('oefNr')->foreign();
            $table->foreign('videoNr')->references('videoNr')->on('videoNr');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('videos');
    }
};
```

This is the code of the one I am trying to link to the other one.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('exercise', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('oefNr');
            $table->char('oefening_naam');
            $table->char('uitleg');
            $table->integer('videoNr')->foreign();
            $table->char('accountNr');
            
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('exercise');
    }
};
```

This is the code for the one I am trying to link to.

I have also tried changing where the key is. So I put it in exercise instead of videos. But the problem with that is that it first creates the exercise table and then the I get a different error. Because it tries to link to a table that doesn't exists yet.

SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'videoNr' (Connection: mysql, SQL: create table `videos` (`videoNr` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `filenaam` char(255) not null, `upload_datum` timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, `oefNr` int not null, `videoNr` bigint unsigned not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'). This is the first error code.

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `videos` add constraint `videos_videonr_foreign` foreign key (`videoNr`) references `videoNr` (`videoNr`)) I have also encounterd this error message.

Comment: Types need to match. `bigIncrement` creates an `UNSIGNED BIGINT`. Might want to take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-id and https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#column-method-foreignId

Comment: If I made it a foreignId  and know I get the 1060 error code. It says I have a duplicate column name now.

Comment: Hey welkom op SO. You should add the exact error message instead of just the code, that gives us the info we need. But if it's the duplicate column error perhaps you can drop the table and run the migration again

Comment: I always run a php serve migrate:fresh so that should drop all tables even if the tables aren't made via a migration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just found the awnser.
This code works.
I changed the where the foreign key was. And also changed my foreign to foreignId. And to change the order they migrate you can change the filename. Because they save the date as yyyymmddhhmmss, you can just put the make it so its created earlier.

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('videos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('videoNr');
            $table->char('filenaam');
            $table->timestamp('upload_datum')->useCurrent();
            $table->integer('oefNr');

        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('videos');
    }
};
?>
```

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        Schema::create('exercise', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('oefNr');
            $table->char('oefening_naam');
            $table->char('uitleg');
            $table->foreignId('videoNr')->references('videoNr')->on('videos'); 
            $table->foreignId('accountNr')->references('accountNr')->on('account');     
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('exercise');
    }
};
```

(edit I pasted my code instead of an image)

Comment: Please paste your code into your answer instead of images. If you're having trouble formatting it, you can check [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). If you're still having issues, someone can edit your answer to format it for you once you include the code.

Answer (score 0):

Note: remove all the bigIntegers that you're assigning foreign keys and use this:
Assuming that your relations are like -> An exercise has `many` videos.

In your parent table `exercise`:

```
$table->id();//add primary keys
```

in your child table `videos`:

```
$table->foreignId('exercise_id')->constrained();
```

if you have model then for adding foreign keys:

```
$table->foreignIdFor(\App\Models\Exercise::class);
```

For using your method the current one make foreign relations like this foreign keys are `bigIncrements` and under the hood `unsignedBigInteger` :

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('exercise_id');
$table->foreign('exercise_id')->references('id')->on('exercise');
```

Comment: In the official laravel documentation it says this. The id method is an alias of the bigIncrements method. By default, the method will create an id column; however, you may pass a column name if you would like to assign a different name to the column. So does changing bigIncrements to Id such a big difference? And thank you for your awnser!

Comment: AI columns are id uses bigIncrements however when you make foreign keys for id you have to match the data type so if you look deep into bigIncrements method of laravel (just cmd+click) on it you will find out that id() uses bigIncrements and in bigincrements ( return $this->unsignedBigInteger($column, true);) is unsignedBigInteger, as you cannot use AI columns for foreign you have to use unsignedBigInteger data type for foreign keys

Comment: Thank you for your comment it is verry helpfull. I have found a method that work tough. But I will surely keep your information in mind for my next project.